# Prepare and execute a query in CQL

Tags: cassandra, cql

Hello i have read a lots of docs and articles, but i couldn't find any CQL commands that can Prepare and execute a query, i want the client to send PREPARE and EXECUTE requests to the server, is there any way to call that requests manually ?

For example i found a PostgreSQL command that Prepare a query then execute it:

```
PREPARE fooplan (int, text, bool, numeric) AS
    INSERT INTO foo VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4);
EXECUTE fooplan(1, 'Hunter Valley', 't', 200.00);
```

How can i do the same in CQL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this in the pure CQL - the prepare/execute is available only in drivers.
So, for example, for [Java](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.8/manual/core/statements/prepared/) it will be:

```java
PreparedStatement prepared = session.prepare(
  "insert into product (sku, description) values (?, ?)");

BoundStatement bound = prepared.bind("234827", "Mouse");
session.execute(bound);
```

In other languages, approach is the same (although there c. You prepare statement once (it should be stored somewhere for reuse), then you create a bound statement providing the actual data values, and that bound statement is then executed.

Comment: thanks :), is there any prepared Cassandra client, that i can check my protocol parsing for PREPARE and EXECUTE requests ?

Comment: I'm not completely understand what do you mean? You can use something like Python for checking your queries